How to install command-line for flutter doctor in ubuntu
I need to install command-line for initializing flutter.
How can I do this?
I have tried flutter doctor but it's required command-line.
So I tried install command-line. But the command is not working.
Please help me.
Thanks.

have you tried ubuntu terminal?

Please provide the commands you have tried. See https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux for instructions on installing flutter on Ubuntu

The built-in terminal should be enough
